# Apache Avro: distinguish `double` and `long` in union values

Tags: python, json, avro

I created the following schema for serializing a set of (`label`, `value`) pairs with Apache Avro (python/1.7.7),

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Measurement",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "label",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "value",
            "type": [ "long", "double", "null" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `python` script for writing data looks like,

```
from avro.datafile import DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumWriter

writer = DataFileWriter(open("data.avro", "w"), DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.append({"label": "A", "value": 0})
writer.append({"label": "B", "value": 0.5})
writer.append({"label": "C", "value": 1})
writer.append({"label": "D", "value": None})
writer.close()
```

And the reader counterpart looks like,

```
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
from avro.io import DatumReader

reader = DataFileReader(open("data.avro", "r"), DatumReader())
for record in reader:
    print(record)
reader.close()
```

Surprisingly, `int` values somehow became `float` when recovered from the reader side, (i.e. `0` became `0.0` and `1` became `1.0`),

```
{u'value': 0.0, u'label': u'A'}
{u'value': 0.5, u'label': u'B'}
{u'value': 1.0, u'label': u'C'}
{u'value': None, u'label': u'D'}
```

I then noticed that if I change the union definition in the schema to (i.e. `double` comes before `long`),

```
"type": [ "double", "long", "null"]
```

Then the types of union values will be correctly recovered on the reader side, i.e.,

```
{u'value': 0, u'label': u'A'}
{u'value': 0.5, u'label': u'B'}
{u'value': 1, u'label': u'C'}
{u'value': None, u'label': u'D'}
```

Now the question is, **is this a reliable means to preserve the type of Avro union values** (i.e. reliable as in well [specified](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html) and implementation/language-neutral)?

Answer (score 0):

Under **Schema Resolution** section on this page:http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html
It says: "*long is promotable to float or double*" 
That's why its working when you define as "type": [ "double", "long", "null"]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but you are referring to schema resolution on the reader side, that is, in case two different schemas are used by the reader and the writer respectively. The problem with my question is how a primitive value is matched against the list of types in a **union** schema when written to the `.avro` file in the first place. given the observed outcome, it looks like `avro` uses the **last** matched type, which is counter-intuitive and not clearly documented.